# List declared directives/controllers in AngularJS module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to list all of the directives and controllers that have been defined for a given angular module?  For example, imagine I define three controllers in the 'main' module (i.e. angular.module('main').controller('MainCtrl',function() {...}).  Is there are way to get the list of those three controllers?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Hmm really hard and not a good thing i think but :

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

console.log(app._invokeQueue[0][2][1]);
```

_invokeQueue is an array if you do that for each entry getting the [0][2][1] you'll see the name of each provider in your module.

If you lok the _invokeQueue alone you'll see a lot of things that you'll like the name of the provider like below but his type too (directive, controller, ...);

But you feel that this is a tricky thing not a good thing a really bad practice but anyway really fun.

Don't use it in production !

Comment: Of course you can implement a custom service ans each controller will say to this service : i'm ... Then you can call this service

Comment: This was very useful in identifying issues with dependency injection after variable mangling my project with uglifyJS. Thanks!


`angular.module('myApp')['_invokeQueue'].forEach(function(value){
   console.log(value[2][1])
})`

You can see the usage of DI Annotation, or lack thereof :D

Comment: if you use `values[2][0]` you actually get a list of injectable names `angular.module('qirt')['_invokeQueue'].forEach(function(value){ console.log(value[2][0]) })`