# List registered custom directives in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing a web app with many custom directives. Is there a way to view all the directives that have been registered for each module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List declared directives/controllers in AngularJS module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986870/list-declared-directives-controllers-in-angularjs-module)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modules have an _invokeQueue, which contains the contents of the module. A function like this:

```
function Directives(module) {
    var directives = [];
    var invokes = angular.module(module)._invokeQueue;
    for (var i in invokes) {
        if (invokes[i][1] === "directive") directives.push(invokes[i][2]);
    }
    return directives;
}
```

will run through the module and grab each element in the invoke queue that are tagged as directives.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7BUw/1/) where you can play with it.

EDIT: I made this slightly more generic, since I'm not sure which case you wanted.

Since modules can include other modules, this will allow you to recursively gather the directives that are in sub modules. http://jsfiddle.net/V7BUw/2/.

the main difference is you need to repeat for every module in the requires array as well:

```
for (var j in module.requires) {
    Directives(module.requires[j], directives);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for making this. Although it seems to be intended to be private, it is interesting that the elements in the `_invokeQueue` array are arrays. You just magically have to know the 2nd field is what type of object it is. Not sure why they didn't use a plain object with keys to explain these cryptic fields.

Comment: Also, just a small comment about your fiddle -- I think HTML output is nicer to work with than console logs, since the fiddle has a designated results panel.