# angular ui-route state template with custom html tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
$stateProvider.state('abc', {
                url: '/:id',
                modal: true,
                template: '<abc></abc>'
            })
```

can I have custom html tag in template property?, e.g. 'abc', I was looking at someone else code but I don't understand how this works, I do have abc.html processed by gulp templatecache stuff. and it is loaded in a modal dialog correctly.

the file is at 'src/app/components/abc/abc.html', how come the template 'abc' knows which html to load? I suppose there must be a definition for 'abc' directive somewhere? but I can't find it.

Comment: It must be a directive.

Comment: I guess so but I searched entire solution and found no directive defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured how it works, turns out the custom html tag is defined by a 'component' and there is some naming convention making this work.
http://blog.grossman.io/angular-1-component-based-architecture-2/

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router

Answer (score 0):

> Can I have custom html tag in template property

Yes, of course. Templates can use custom directives no matter how [they are defined](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates).

There should be an 'abc' directive somewhere in your module code or one of its dependencies.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087752/list-registered-custom-directives-in-angularjs) to be able to list the registered directives of your module and submodules in the console.

Comment: i can't find abc defined anywhere......i also used your code to list any directive but find nothing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use custom html. UI Router provides you two choices, either you give the `template` or the `templateUrl`, which for the first one you have to write your html in a string literal, and latter you can set a html file location.

using `template` with string literal:

```
$stateProvider.state('abc', {
  url: '/:id',
  modal: true,
  template: '<abc></abc>' // this is correct!
})
```

using `templateUrl` with html files.

```
$stateProvider.state('abc', {
  url: '/:id',
  modal: true,
  templateUrl: '/path/to/abc.html' // if you have a file named `abc.html` in directory `path/to`, the template will be loaded
})
```

Comment: is it possible that I use custom html without defining any directive?