# AngularJS - Get List of All Registered Services?

Tags: angularjs

Can I get a list of all registered directives, services, controllers, etc. *at runtime* . . . ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List declared directives/controllers in AngularJS module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986870/list-declared-directives-controllers-in-angularjs-module)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can get a list of the providers (ie services/directives/controllers/factories/etc) for each module, although the list is kind of cryptic.

Say you have the following:

```
var mod = angular.module('myModule', []);
mod.factory('fact1', function($dependency1, $dependency2){ ... });
mod.service('serv1', function($dependency3, $dependency4){ ... });
mod.controller('ctrl1', function($dependency2, $dependency3){ ... });
mod.factory('fact2', function($dependency1, $dependency4){ ... });
...
```

Then the `mod` variable will contain an attribute called `mod._invokeQueue` that will contain an array of all the providers that are part of that module.  The `_invokeQueue` will look something like this:

```
[
    ['$provide', 'factory', Arguments['fact1', ['$dependency1', '$dependency2', function(){}],
    ['$provide', 'service', Arguments['serv1', ['$dependency3', '$dependency4', function(){}],
    ['$provide', 'controller', Arguments['ctrl1', ['$dependency2', '$dependency3', function(){}],
    ['$provide', 'factory', Arguments['fact2', ['$dependency1', '$dependency4', function(){}]
    ...
]
```

So you can search through that `mod._invokeQueue` for each provider that it contains.

But that will only contain the list of providers for that specific module. If you want to get a list of all of the dependent modules, you will need to loop through the `mod.requires` array.

If the module has module-level dependencies, like so:

```
var mod = angular.module('myModule', ['otherModule1','otherModule2']);
```

Then the `mod` object will also have a `mod.requires` array that contains the names of those module dependencies, like so:

```
angular.forEach(mod.requires, function(requiredModuleName){
    // first get a reference to the required module by calling angular.module()
    var requiredMod = angular.module(requiredModuleName);
    // requiredMod will have its own ._invokeQueue
    // requiredMod._invokeQueue will look like the _invokeQueue from above
    ...
    // do something with the additional providers in _invokeQueue
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  Very helpful.  I wish Angular just exposed some metadata about itself in a kinder way - getServices(), etc.

Comment: If I do `var mod = angular.module('myModule');...` from Chrome dev's console when the app runs, it doesn't show anything in the array. Is this supposed to be in the .js code itself and not runtime?

Comment: Yeah, you can't modify a module once it has been loaded (as far as I know), so you'd have to do some sort of console logging or something to see what is inside (such as adding a `console.log()` statement right after the module is declared in the code)

Comment: Actually you can. You can register new modules/controllers etc directly in the console of Chrome and even from IE or any other browser that supports a console. If you type in the console angular.module('myApp')._invokeQueue you will see the array of all registered components.

Comment: I stand corrected. Apparently you can modify a module on the fly.  Thanks to @GxG for the clarification.

Comment: is there any way to retrieve the actual object of the service/factory etc.? I see this returns the name, dependancies and creator function but can I use it to get the cached object (once instantiated by angular)?

Comment: @LukeDeighton, I'm not sure what you mean by "the actual object" or the "cached object"?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to get the factory object, where you do: 

app.factory('myFactory', function() { 
  return {} <--- this thing here
}); Edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276183/angularjs-retrieve-factory-object-at-runtime-dynamically

Comment: Really interesting! Anyone know if there is any way to read all the methods in $resource that I retrieve in that method?

Comment: @teone, what do you mean? Why would you want to read all the methods in `$resource`?

Comment: I was wondering if I could dinamically generate decorators for all the $resource service attached to my application, as I would like to add a caching system, then I realized that $http has his own cache method... So it's not needed anymore, but is still interesting...

Answer (score 43):

Try this:

```
angular.module('MyApp')['_invokeQueue'].forEach(function(value){ 
    console.log(value[1] + ": " + value[2][0]);
})
```

Comment: Give that man a cookie ! Best answer to me; it really does list all of them in the console.

Answer (score 32):

### Here's how you can get most services

Ie: **constants**, **values**, **factories**, **services**.

```
    function allServices(mod, r) {
      var inj = angular.element(document).injector().get;
      if (!r) r = {};
      angular.forEach(angular.module(mod).requires, function(m) {allServices(m,r)});
      angular.forEach(angular.module(mod)._invokeQueue, function(a) {
        try { r[a[2][0]] = inj(a[2][0]); } catch (e) {}
      });
      return r;
    };

    allMyServices = allServices('myApp');
```

Now when you type in the console `allMyServices.` you'll get an auto-complete list of them.

---

The function above can fail in certain situations where `angular.element(document).injector()` returns undefined. You can use the function below instead...

---

### Alternate Method

```
    var inj;
    function allServices(mod, r) {
      if (!r) {
        r = {};
        inj = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector().get;
      }
      angular.forEach(angular.module(mod).requires, function(m) {allServices(m,r)});
      angular.forEach(angular.module(mod)._invokeQueue, function(a) {
        try { r[a[2][0]] = inj(a[2][0]); } catch (e) {}
      });
      return r;
    };

    allMyServices = allServices('myApp');
```

Now when you type in the console `allMyServices.` you'll get an auto-complete list of them.

---

#### Note: With either method, be sure to replace `'MyApp'` with your **module** name.

Comment: `allMyServices = allServices(document.querySelector('[ng-app]').getAttribute('ng-app'));`

Comment: This can still potentially fail if the app was loaded with [angular.bootstrap()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap), in which case my favorite thing to do when I need an injector is grab the first element with the `ng-scope` class, since any element within an app will return the same injector: `angular.element('.ng-scope').injector();`

Comment: The autocomplete is golden.

Comment: To access the property of a specific module, your answer helped me come up with this:
`angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector().get(Modules.YourModuleId).yourProperty`

Answer (score 0):

I've created a GitHub gist with some code that can output the dependencies in a [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) friendly format. Which means you should be able to visualize the dependency graph.

See https://gist.github.com/dlidstrom/a2f787cef41ea4fcb8aa74d459f49270.