# Angular Kendo Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

Is there any documentation or demo page of sorts which lists all the directives available for all the angular kendo controls. I figured out quite a few of them by prefixing "k-" as in "k-min","k-max" and giving a "-" after ever logical word as in kendo-drop-down-list etc. But this involves lot of trial and error and I am pretty much stuck with all grid events since none of the directives i give seem to work. If any one could point me to any such documentation or blog that would be great!Thanks a ton

PS: I have done a lot of searching on Google and couldn't find any such documentation/blog

Answer (score 3):

Use the Kendo UI documentation:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/

For example, with a button:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/button

The properties you pass to the configuration function are what are mapped to the k-prefixes, i.e. in the case of button notice there are options like `enable` and `icon` therefore you would wire it up like:

```
<kendo-button k-enable='true' k-icon="'icon'"></kendo-button>
```

There is a great introduction to how this works here:

http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/13-06-24/announcing-angular-kendo-ui

Answer (score 3):

I found some useful code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411502/angular-get-list-of-all-registered-services) that I ran in Chrome console to list the names of all the directives in the kendo.directives module.  I don't want to list them all here so I created a blog entry about it and posted them there.

Although I wasn't able to find what I was looking for, I hope this helps someone else.

The code I used to generate the list:

```
angular.module('kendo.directives')['_invokeQueue'].forEach(function(value) {
    if (value[1] === 'directive') {
        console.log(value[2][0]);
    }
 });
```

My blog post containing the list: http://answersicouldntfindanywhereelse.blogspot.com/2016/12/kendo-ui-directives.html

Answer (score 2):

The particular problem you are having is as follows:

the `k-` prefix works for configuration options as you rightly mention `k-min` and `k-max` but for events you need to use `k-on-`  for example `k-on-change`.

Nowadays you can find useful Angular Kendo examples on each Kendo widget example page. Here is the one for grid:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular