# Cannot add second AngularJS Service Factory

Tags: angularjs, rest, factory

I try to add 2 Services to my AngularJS Module. One should access my Employees and one my Products, but I get an `Unknown provider: EmployeeServiceProvider <- EmployeeService <- BookingController`.

All Javascript-Files are added to the html.

App/Module

```
var coffeewatchApp = angular.module('coffeewatchApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'coffeewatchControllers',
    'coffeewatchServices'
]);

//Routing

var coffeewatchControllers = angular.module('coffeewatchControllers', []);
var coffeewatchServices = angular.module('coffeewatchServices', []);
```

EmployeeService.js

```
var coffeewatchServices = angular.module('coffeewatchServices', ['ngResource']);

var employeeServiceUrlPart = "EmployeeService/";
coffeewatchServices.factory('EmployeeService', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('all/', {}, {
            all:     {method:'GET',url:REST_BASEURL+employeeServiceUrlPart+"all", params:{}, isArray:true}
        });
    }]);
```

ProductController.js is exactly the same but with Product

```
var coffeewatchServices = angular.module('coffeewatchServices', ['ngResource']);

var productServiceUrlPart = "ProductService/";
coffeewatchServices.factory('ProductService', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('all/', {}, {
            all: {method:'GET',url:REST_BASEURL+productServiceUrlPart+"all", params:{}, isArray:true}
        });
    }]);
```

Controller accessing the two Services

```
coffeewatchControllers.controller('BookingController', ['$scope', 'EmployeeService', 'ProductService',
    function ($scope, EmployeeService, ProductService) {
        $scope.employees = EmployeeService.all();
        $scope.products = ProductService.all();
}]);
```

Any help is appreciated; Thanks in advance.

`EDIT:`
I implemented the `EmployeeService` first and everything was working great.
So I don't really understand why adding the `ProductService` kills my `EmployeeService`. The only thing I can think of is that the `ProductService` somehow "overwrites" my `EmployeeService` because it gets injected second.

All added JS-Files in index.html

```
<script src="js/config/app-config.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/DashboardController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/StatisticController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/BookingController.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/EmployeeService.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/ProductService.js"></script>
```

`EDITEDIT`
After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25353703/3286569) answer I am even more confused why my code is not working, but maybe the other code will help somone spotting the difference.

Comment: Have you added reference to EmployeeService.js in index.html?

Comment: Yes I did. But I added the part from the Index.html to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both of your controller files, retrieve the module like this (remove dependency list)  -

```
var coffeewatchServices = angular.module('coffeewatchServices');
```

Add the dependency to `ngResource` here instead, while declaring in App/Module -

```
var coffeewatchServices = angular.module('coffeewatchServices', ['ngResource']);
```

Your module is getting re-created on the second call in `ProductController`, so overriding previous module and service definitions.

Comment: My Code is at home, but it seems that you are absolutly right. The Official [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) even has it's own section "Creation versus Retrieval"