# Get list of AngularJS' objects and variables in Developer Console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is more for debugging and exploring the current state of my application in the browser. I followed this advise

[List declared directives/controllers in AngularJS module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986870/list-declared-directives-controllers-in-angularjs-module)

However, I don't see anything like that in `_invokeQueue`.

```
console.log(app._invokeQueue[0][2][1]);
undefined VM363:2
undefined
```

How does AngularJS store their directives, services, controllers objects and variables? What's the best way to drill into each in the browser memory? Assuming I know all the naming.

Answer (score 2):

There is angular batarang for chrome.

Here is the [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know Batarang but it doesn't have a list of directives, services, filters. It only has model, which is very limited.